# resize stackpane in javafx with css

Tags: java, css, javafx-2

i'm working with javaFx and i want resize my stackPane or add border, how can i do that?
and how can i position it in the center or my window?

this is my code:

```
 final HBox box =  new HBox();
        box.getStyleClass().add("box");
        final ToolBar outils = new ToolBar();
        final Button file = new Button("fichier");
        final Button as2 = new Button("AS2");
        final Button ftp = new Button("FTP");
        final Button arrow = new Button("Liaison");
        file.setGraphic(new ImageView("/images/file.png"));
        as2.setGraphic(new ImageView("/images/http.png"));
        ftp.setGraphic(new ImageView("/images/ftp.png"));
        arrow.setGraphic(new ImageView("/images/Arrow.png"));
        box.getChildren().addAll(file,as2,ftp,arrow);
        outils.getItems().addAll(box);



        // ma zone de dessin
        final StackPane paint = new StackPane();
          paint.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;");
        paint.setPrefSize(0, 690);
        paint.getStyleClass().add("paint");
```

and this is my window :

[image]

tks

Answer (score 0):

try  this ;
in  your controller

@FXML StackPane pane;

```
public void Action(){
.
.
.
    pane.setPrefHeight(value);
    pane.setPrefWidth(value);
.
.
.
```

Comment: tks for your answer, it works for Height but i can't resize the the with and that's what i want to do

Comment: i must be work for the width i think chek for the width property in your FXML file or css file if there is a witth value it can block the setprefwith function
sory for my bad english